# How mailtester works

Tags: python, validation, email

I am trying to validate email addresses without sending a mail. I wrote a code in python as follows:

```
import socket
import smtplib

host = socket.gethostname()

server = smtplib.SMTP()
server.set_debuglevel(0)

# I am taking mxRecord based on priority using dnspython
server.connect(mxRecord)
server.helo(host)

server.mail('mail@domain.com')
code, message = server.rcpt(str(emailToVerify))
print "Code - %d" % code
print "Message - %s" % message
server.quit()
if code == 250:
    print('Valid')
else:
    print('Invalid')
```

In mail tester apart from valid and invalid we find **Server doesn't allow e-mail address verification**. How to find that in my code?

I am getting only two response code i.e.

> 250 (for valid and partially valid - Server doesn't allow e-mail
>   address verification)

and

> 550 (for invalid e-mail)

Now how should I distinguish between a valid and partially valid email?

> If the E-mail address entered turns green, it is valid.
>
> If the E-mail address entered turns red, it is invalid.
>
> **If the E-mail address entered turns yellow, Server doesn't allow
>   e-mail address verification.(How to achieve this scenario?)**

Please help me with this issue.

Comment: What do you understand as a "partially valid email"? What's the difference between a partially valid and an invalid email?

Comment: @Noshii Partially valid email according to mail tester gives the message as `Server doesn't allow e-mail address verification` and valid gives the message as `E-mail address is valid`

Comment: I got that one but what would be a partially valid email? If there is no major difference you can just check if you got 550 back, if so it's invalid, and in any other case you could mark it valid, if I understood you right.

Comment: Its like in mailtester, they identify the email id as green and yellow. I want the same. But I don't get how to distinguish between e-mails and how to display it as green or yellow. So only I am asking how to do that part?